# Nestjs Dto validation and render ejs page

Tags: javascript, nestjs, class-validator

Nestjs Dto validation error returns JSON response but I want to render and pass validation errors to ejs file when validation fails

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not catch the exception in an [exception filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) and then call `res.render()` with the file you want to render and metadata for the file?

```js
@Catch(BadRequestException)
export class BadRequestFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: BadRequestException, host: ArgumentHost) {
    const res = host.switchToHttp().getResponse();
    res.render('error', { errorInfo: exception });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i can catch exceptions but should I do this for all of my DTO class validators because I want to render different ejs files according to my resources.

Comment: Do you want to render a different error page per DTO?

Comment: Yes, I find out that instead of rendering a page I have to redirect to a page that I give from the constructor of the filter class.

Comment: But now how can I flash messages in nest js